# Good resource for a test case document

Tags: testcase, documentation

I am wondering if there is a template for test case documentation online, preferably on excel. After searching for some useful information, I am not finding anything I like. I have written these by myself over the years and am just trying to speed the process up. I realize that I will be making my own by tweaking what I find, but I need a good starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link should be a good start:

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-case-template-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few links which may also be useful to you :

http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/index.php?document_srl=4217458&mid=download

http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/index.php?document_srl=4189478&mid=book

http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/index.php?document_srl=1671349&mid=download

http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/index.php?document_srl=850017&mid=download

http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/index.php?document_srl=824754&mid=download

Answer (score 0):

I have just read a fantastic piece that provides important best practices for writing test cases, and on the importance of documenting it in the first place, written by Randell Rice.

[Realizing Test Cases, Test Scripts and Test Scenarios as Valued Testing Assets](https://www.practitest.com/qa-learningcenter/best-practices/writing-test-cases-scriptes-scenarios-importance/)